# mlpyをv3.5.0にアップグレードできない

Tags: python

現在Pythonは2.7を使用しており、現在のmlpyは0.1.0です。
mlpy.dtw_std()を利用したく、[手引き](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/install.html#download)に従って3.5.0のインストールを試みていますが、下記のエラーが出てうまくいきません。
解決法ご教示ください。

```
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o -L/path/to/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/mlpy/gsl.so
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/path/to/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgsl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: ライブラリ`lgsl`が見つからないと言ってます。`-L/path/to/lib`は`lgsl`が存在するライブラリの実際のパスにしないとダメだと思います。手引きの方はライブラリの場所は環境によって異なるのでメッセージ的に"path to lib"と書いてあるだけですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変恐縮ながら、具体的には、どのような処理を行えばよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: `GSL`がインストールされているパスを指定してくださいとしか…手引きでいうところの`--rpath=/path/to/lib`の部分です。普通にインストールしていれば`--include-dirs`の指定も`--rpath`の指定も不要なようですが。

Comment: 解決いたしました！ありがとうございます。